# Is it recommended to memorize the Quran without understanding the words?

Tags: quran, islamic-basis

Is there any hadith or Quranic ayat which encourages just memorizing Quran without understanding it? In our country Pakistan, it is a well established common thing to memorize Quran but those people don't understand even a single ayat and still think that they will be able to provide intercession for their family on the day of qiyamah. Please give references for both sides of this argument.

Answer (score 1):

Asalmu Walaykum

It is recommended that you memorize, and understand the quran. According to this verse of the holy quran:

“(This is) a Book (the Qur’aan) which We have sent down to you, full of blessings, that they may ponder over its Verses, and that men of understanding may remember”
[Saad 38:29].

However, it is okay to memorize without understanding it. One who memorized the quran will have a crown over his head, and will have the reward, and one who understands and has Memorized the holy quran will get more reward. There is nothing wrong with memorizing without understanding it.